# Read from file and put data into a tuple for a database

Tags: python, database, tuples

So I need to input information about employees into different strings or a tuple from a file. The format is known so I can extract them and know which order the variables need to be used but I need to split each string into each 5 different items into a tuple format or dict.

```
employeeList = list()
employeeDict = {}

f = open("/Users/JamesDonnelly/Downloads/emps.txt")
myLine = f.readline()
while (len(myLine)>0):
    for word in myLine.split(' '):
        print(word)
        if len(str(word)) != 0 :
            variable = word
    myLine = f.readline()
f.close()
```

Right now this just prints out each of the 5 words in the file. So the first is customerID, then pay , job etc. There's 5 of them. I need to assign the first 5 to 5 different variables, then loop round and assign it to the next 5. Then after it's a nice list of a list or list of a dict or database-y set up I can loop through and search for specific things and return them.

Comment: Can you give us an example of some lines of emps.txt and how do you want to organize the employees?

Comment: why not simply:
`a,b,c,d,e = myLine.split():` ?

Answer (score 3):

Shorter and cleaner. You can extract variables from a list/tuple in this easy way.

```
with open("/Users/JamesDonnelly/Downloads/emps.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        customerID, pay, job, foo, foo2 = line.strip().split()
```

Comment: How would, after I've extracted the tuples put them into a list or similar format so I could search and display results?

Comment: create a list and use append to put the values to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
customer=['Cust ID', 'Pay', 'Job', 'X', 'Y']
data={field:[] for field in customer}
with open(in_file) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        for field, datum in zip(customer,line.split()):
             data[field].append(datum)
```

Then, given a file like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

You would end up with a data structure like this:

```
{'Y': ['5', '10', '15'], 'Pay': ['2', '7', '12'], 'Job': ['3', '8', '13'], 'Cust ID': ['1', '6', '11'], 'X': ['4', '9', '14']}
```

Then you access the data this way:

```
>>> data['Job'][1]
'8'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign them like this:

```
customerID, pay, job, something1, something2 = myLine.split(' ')
```

then you have each information in one variable and can now assign them to a dictionary with key `customerID`:

first create dictionary `log = {}` then:

```
log[customerID] = pay, job, something1, something2
```